# Intellisense in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net

For some reason the Intellisense in vb.net stopped working when I use an Aggregate Lambda expression inside a With statement.

```
With Me.SalesPackage
    .WebLinks = Sales.Where(Function(f) f.Current.BookerWeb > 0).Count
    .WebAmount = Aggregate o In Sales.Where(Function(f) f.Current.WebBooker > 0) Into 
    Sum(o.Current.WebPrice)
End With
```

If I insert a new line between .WebLinks and .WebAmount and start typing, it works. But it won't work if I do it after the Aggregate statement...

Any ideas?

Comment: Post this to connect.microsoft.com

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, when Intellisense stops working, there's certainly a syntax error somewhere in the Linq expression.

Comment: True, but in this case the intellisense works for the same expression if I take it outside the With statement...